# jQuery CSS not firing after Ajax load - can't use an on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a somewhat special situation where I need to load a background image dependent on data returning in a page that is loaded with Ajax.

Obviously `$(document).ready` doesn't work here and the usual answer is to supply and .on click event handler, but in this situation there is no event to trigger, I'm basically trying to load a background image on page load.

I'm grabbing the url of the image on the newly loaded page and setting it to a var, then trying to use that url for the background image of an element :

This is how it looks :

```
<script>
var bgImage = '<?php echo TEMP_LOC . $track->track_id . '-bg.jpg'; ?>';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.single-t').css('background', 'url("' + bgImage + '")');
});
</script>
```

This works when the page is accessed directly but fails when loaded via ajax.

The CSS has to be inline, I can't move this out to a separate CSS file as it relies on the page loaded to get the image URL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by just setting it inline on the actual div:

```
<div class="single-t" style="background: url('<?php echo TEMP_LOC . $track->track_id . '-bg.jpg'; ?>')">
```